# get the position of every element in a list after a certain position in another list in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of positions of an item from a `list=[1,4,5,8]`.

I want to use these positions to find the occurrence of another item in the original list after these positions.

I was wondering if there is one liner using enumerate after certain position and put it into a for loop for the certain position keeps changing.

Here is an example:

```
list1=['a','b','a','c','d','b','b','a','e','b','f'] 
list2#positions of 'a'=[0,2,5]
```

I want all the first occurrences of `b` after `a` but not before `a`.

Comment: No it doesn't - please give more detailed examples of your lists, and what you expect as the output

Comment: do you want this `orignallist[list[i]]` this is valid expression yes

Comment: list1=['a','b','a','c','d','b','b','a','e','b','f'] list2#positions of 'a'=[0,2,5] I want all the positions of b after a.

Comment: @mparida Sometimes it's easier to read if you edit your question instead of trying to type code into the comments.

Comment: @mparida add this comment in question instead..

Comment: @mparida, either you're going to need to do some work clarifying exactly what you want, or you're going to need to attempt to write some code yourself, and then ask for help. It is extremely difficult to tell what you mean by your question.

Comment: What is your expected output for the example you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to find them.  For this version, an exception will be raised if the value is not found.

```
>>> s = 'abacdaebfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxabc'
>>> finder = lambda lst, inds, x: [lst.index(x, i) for i in inds]
>>> finder(s, [0, 2, 3, 10], 'a')
[0, 2, 5, 30]
```

This will work if `s` is either a string or a list.

Comment: Thanks and yes I can work on the exception.

Comment: Exception is handled in my answer.

Comment: No need to shortcut your `lst`, since `.index()` takes a `start` and `end` argument.

Comment: Please explain me the finder and lambda in the code. I haven't used lambda very much.

Comment: Thanks askewchan for the exception handled

Comment: `lambda` is used to created a one-line function definition in python (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms). `finder` is just the name I assigned to the function.  Left of the ":" are the args and to the right is the return value.

Comment: Thanks @askewchan.  I edited the answer. That makes it even shorter.

Comment: I modified bogatron's algorithm. It's much faster now.
finder = lambda lst, inds, x: [lst.index(x,inds[i],inds[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(inds)-1)]

Comment: @mparaida Your modified version misses the last value (at least in my example).

Comment: Hi can we add a line to extract the position of all the b's after a using the same algorithm.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  There's no reason you can't call `finder` a second time, replacing "a" with "b" for the third argument.

Comment: I tried but it gives me the same result.                         list1=['a','b','a','c','d','b','b','a','e','b','f']                   l1=[i for i, x in enumerate(list1) if x == 'a']              t1=finder(list1,l1, 'b')                          t2=finder(list1,t1, 'b') [1,5,9] but I also want the b after 5. Hope this helps.

Comment: Then you are either asking for every 'b' after the first index or there are more details to what you are asking.  I suggest you ask a new question on SO since this is different than your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find the marks first, before finding the first instances of the targets after them:

```
def find_after(lst, target, mark):
    marks = []
    while True:
        try:
            marks.append(lst.index(mark,marks[-1] if marks else 0))
        except ValueError:
            # no more 'a's were found
            break
    targets = []
    for m in marks:
        try:
            targets.append(lst.index(target, m))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return targets
```

Which works as:

```
find_after(['a','b','a','c','d','b','b','a','e','b','f'], 'b', 'a')
#[1,5,9] # the locations of the 'b's (target) after the 'a's (mark)
```